# Why Is This Function Bijective?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $$f(f(f(n))) + f(f(n)) +f(n)=3n$$

The first line in the solution says that $f$ is bijective. Why? I understand the rest of the solution, except this.

Comment: Injectivity: $f(n)=f(p) \implies 3n=3p$.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to prove surjectivity without proving that $f$ is the identity altogether. Fortunately, injectivity is enough.

Comment: Maybe the source you have uses the (very common) phrase "one-to-one function", which is synonymous with "injective function", while you are more acquainted with "one-to-one *correspondence*", which is synonymous with "bijective function".

Answer (score 3):

I found a proof showing that $f$ must be bijective, but it immediately solves the whole problem. I do not know if $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ in your notation, so I will assume $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$. Note that $f(n) \geq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence,
$$
3 \leq f(f(f(1))) + f(f(1)) + f(1) = 3.
$$
So $f(1) = f(f(1)) = f(f(f(1))) = 1$. Inductively, suppose $f(k) = k$ for all $k \leq m - 1$. Then since Olivier Oloa already proved that $f$ is injective, we see that $f(n) \geq m$ for $n \geq m$. Hence,
$$
3m \leq f(f(f(m))) + f(f(m)) + f(m) = 3m,
$$
showing that $f(m) = m$. Surjectivity follows, but also that $f$ is the identity function.

Comment: So we didn't need to show that $f$ is bijective to solve this problem? Also, I used a pretty similar, if not same, method to solve this.

Comment: No, at least as far I know. BTW, I think the comment of G. Sassatelli will be the most accurate concerning whether or not we need to show that $f$ is bijective.